# Search API: AND Vs OR

Tags: support, api, search-engine

Using API, if you search for 'orange icon' in the title:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/search?order=desc&sort=activity&intitle=orange%20icon&site=stackoverflow (5results)

but a site search with: **+title:orange +title:icon** :

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Btitle%3Aorange+%2Btitle%3Aicon&submit=search (9 results)

it's strange that it differs? (the 5 above results are in the 9)

but I wanted to know, onsite search **title:orange title:icon** gives results with at least one term in the title, with the the 9 above in first (5000+)

How to do the equivalent with API? or maybe the API doesn't support OR, they are done by merging in the site search?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/search?order=desc&sort=activity&intitle=orange%20icon&site=stackoverflow is searching for "orange icon" (from **intitle=orange%20icon**)

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Btitle%3Aorange+%2Btitle%3Aicon&submit=search is searching for "orange" and "icon"

The subtle difference is the first is looking for words with a single space between them (%20) and the second is looking for those words anywhere in the title.

Comment: and any solution to have api find for multiple words in title?, https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/search?order=desc&sort=activity&intitle=orange|icon&site=stackoverflow is not working better

Comment: @cyril, actually, I can't seem to find anything. `intitle=orange&intitle=icon` seems to act as an OR (30 returned question ids). perhaps someone who works more with the API can help

Comment: o right : &intitle=orange&intitle=icon, tried many things except that, seems doing a 'OR' but still less than the 5000+ on SO, mysterious